# How to import requireJS modules by name in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

Assume in an Angular project we have added all controllers as modules by require.js:

```
// js/controllers/modules.js
define("appControllers", ['angular'], function (ng) {
  'use strict';
  return ng.module('app.controllers', []);
});
```

and all controllers are defined in separated files

```
// js/controllers/home-controller.js
define(['appControllers'], function (controllers) {
  'use strict';
  controllers.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

      // my logics here

  }]);
});
```

usage in application

```
// js/app.js
define([
  'angular',
  './controllers'
], function (angular) {
  'use strict';

  return angular.module('app', [
    'app.controllers'
  ]);
});
```

This works very fine as long as controllers are in `js/controllers`  directory. but apparently it doesn't work after grunt minifies JS files into a single `main.min.js` file.

How to change this code to work in a single minified `main.min.js` file?

**Additional context**
I tried to use the name of modules instead of their path, but I couldn't get it to work.

I get this error :

```
http://127.0.0.1:9001/javascripts/appControllers.js 
Uncaught Error: Script error for "appControllers", needed by: app
```

Comment: So what errors get thrown and where? *"Doesn't work"* is not a proper problem description

Comment: @charlietfl thanks a lot - I'v added the error I got .

Answer (score 0):

maybe too late.but for loading requireJs modules by name you can call requirejs.config() method before bootstrapping angular.

sample code :

// before bootstrapping ...

```js
requirejs.config({
            waitSeconds:60,
            baseUrl: exports.paths.scripts.in.get(),
            paths: {
                "jquery": bowerComponents + "jquery/dist/jquery.min",
                "tinymce": bowerComponents + "tinymce/tinymce.min",
                "angular-tinymce": bowerComponents + "angular-ui-tinymce/dist/tinymce.min",
                "angular": bowerComponents + "angular/angular.min",
                "angular-ui-router": bowerComponents + "angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min",
                "angular-re-tree": bowerComponents + "re-tree/re-tree.min",
                "angular-device-detector": bowerComponents + "ng-device-detector/ng-device-detector.min",
                "angular-messages": bowerComponents + "angular-messages/angular-messages.min",
                "angular-local-storage": nodeModules + "angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.min",
                "angular-resource": bowerComponents + "angular-resource/angular-resource.min",
                "adm-dtp": bowerComponents + "adm-dtp/dist/ADM-dateTimePicker.min",
                "angular-animate": nodeModules + "angular-animate/angular-animate.min",
                "angular-aria": nodeModules + "angular-aria/angular-aria.min",
                "angular-material": nodeModules + "angular-material/angular-material.min",
                "material-steppers": nodeModules + "md-steppers/dist/md-steppers.min",
                "angular-sanitize": nodeModules + "angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min",
                "spin": nodeModules + "angular-spinner/node_modules/spin.js/spin.min",
                "angular-spinner": nodeModules + "angular-spinner/angular-spinner.min",
                "angular-resizable": nodeModules + "angular-resizable/src/angular-resizable",
                "ng-file-upload": nodeModules + "ng-file-upload/dist/ng-file-upload.min",
                "angular-material-icons": nodeModules + "angular-material-icons/angular-material-icons.min",
                "underscore": bowerComponents + "underscore/underscore-min",
                "jquery-nanoscroller": bowerComponents + "angular-nanoscroller/jquery.nanoscroller.min",
                "angular-nanoscroller": bowerComponents + "angular-nanoscroller/scrollable",
                "angular-material-data-table": bowerComponents + "angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table",
                "element-queries": nodeModules + "css-element-queries/src/ElementQueries",
                "jquery-resize": "vendors/jquery.resize",
                "jquery-print": "vendors/jQuery.print",
                "ng-scrollable": "vendors/ng-scrollable",
                "angular-truncate": "vendors/truncate",
                "string": nodeModules + "string/dist/string.min",
                "masonry": bowerComponents + "masonry/dist/masonry.pkgd.min"
            },
            shim: {
                "jquery": {
                    deps: [],
                    exports: "$"
                }, "jquery-resize": {
                    deps: ["jquery"],
                    exports: "$"
                }, "jquery-print": {
                    deps: ["jquery"],
                    exports: "$"
                }, "jquery-nanoscroller": {
                    deps: ["jquery"],
                    exports: "$"
                }, "angular": {
                    deps: [],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "angular-ui-router": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "angular-tinymce": {
                    deps: ["angular","tinymce"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "tinymce": {
                    deps: [],
                    exports: "tinyMCE"
                }, "angular-local-storage": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "angular-animate": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "angular-aria": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "angular-material": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                },"material-steppers": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "angular-material-icons": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "angular-re-tree": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "angular-device-detector": {
                    deps: ["angular-re-tree"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "angular-resizable": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "angular-messages": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "angular-truncate": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "angular-sanitize": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "angular-resource": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                },"ng-file-upload": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "adm-dtp": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "angular-nanoscroller": {
                    deps: ["angular", "jquery-nanoscroller"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "angular-material-data-table": {
                    deps: ["angular","angular-material"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }, "ng-scrollable": {
                    deps: ["angular"],
                    exports: "angular"
                }
            }
        });
```

//requirejs module resolution by name + bootstrapping angular ....

```js
define(["jquery",
        "angular",
        "angular-ui-router",
        "angular-animate",
        "angular-aria",
        "angular-material",
        "material-steppers",
        "angular-device-detector",
        "angular-resizable",
        "angular-messages",
        "angular-local-storage",
        "underscore",
        "element-queries",
        "string",
        "jquery-resize",
        'angular-material-icons',
        'angular-spinner',
        'angular-nanoscroller',
        'angular-truncate',
        'angular-sanitize',
        'angular-resource',
        'jquery-print',
        'ng-file-upload',
        'adm-dtp',
        'angular-material-data-table',
        'ng-scrollable',
        'tinymce',
        'angular-tinymce',
        "masonry"],
    function (jquery,
              angular,
              angularUiRouter,
              angularAnimate,
              angularAria,
              angularMaterial,
              materialSteppers,
              angularDeviceDetector,
              angularResizable,
              angularMessages,
              angularLocalStorage,
              underscore,
              elementQueries,
              string,
              jqueryResize,
              angularMaterialIcons,
              angularSpinner,
              angularNanoScroller,
              angularTruncate,
              angularSanitize,
              angularResource,
              jqueryPrint,
              ngFileUpload,
              admDateTimePicker,
              angularMaterialDataTable,
              ngScrollable,
              tinyMce,
              angularTinyMce,
              masonry) {

        var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'LocalStorageModule', 'angularResizable', 'ng.deviceDetector', 'ngMdIcons', 'angularSpinner', 'sun.scrollable', 'md.data.table', 'truncate', 'ngResource', 'ngScrollable', "ngSanitize", "ngAnimate", 'ADM-dateTimePicker', 'ngFileUpload','md-steppers','ui.tinymce'],
            function config() {

            });

        app.run(function ($rootScope, $state,security,materialDataTable,state) {
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
                if (toState.data && toState.data.secure && !security.isAuthenticated()) {
                    $state.go("root.login");
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState) {
                if(toState.data.resetDataContextAfterStateActivated) {
                    //create new context or reset preexist context
                    materialDataTable.getContext(state.current.getDataServiceName(), state.current.getDataService(),true);
                }
            });

        });

        var afterBootstrapTasks = [];

        function startAngular() {
            var root = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            angular.bootstrap(root, ["app"]);
            var injector = angular.element(root).injector();
            afterBootstrapTasks.forEach(function (item) {
                item(injector);
            });
        }

        return {
            jquery: jquery,
            angular: angular,
            angularUiRouter: angularUiRouter,
            underscore: underscore,
            elementQueries: elementQueries,
            jqueryResize: jqueryResize,
            string: string,
            masonry: masonry,
            app: app,
            startAngular: startAngular,
            storage: angularLocalStorage,
            directives: [],
            afterBootstrapTasks: afterBootstrapTasks,
            tinyMce:tinyMce,
        };
    });
```

this was the script loading part of my last angular js project that I was working on it last year. now everything is changed. and angularjs is not my favorite javascript framework. I hope my answer can be helpful.

Comment: The OP's problem is certainly not that they just are not configuring RequireJS because the OP says "**This works very fine as long as controllers are in js/controllers directory.** but apparently it doesn't work after grunt minifies JS files into a single main.min.js file." (Emphasis added.) There's an issue *after minification*.